# Why won't Mule properly parse XML returned from a webservice?

Tags: xml, mule, mule-component, anypoint-studio

I'm a bit new to this, but I'm having a problem that must have a straightforward solution I don't know about.

I'm using the HTTP connector to call out to a webservice, and the webservice returns valid XML. I can't then automatically return the XML unmodified or I get

```
No serializer found for class org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.BufferInputStream and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer
```

So I guess that's because the response is streamed and I need to do Byte Array to [whatever] first. However, when I do this, quotes and new line characters get escaped like this

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\r\n<root xmlns=\"http://xmlns.whatever.com"><PERSON type=\"staff\"><ID><![CDATA[00100762]]></ID></PERSON></root>"
```

If I try to use the transformer to turn it into a plain string, xml, json, or whatever, I end up with all these escaped characters. If I transform into a string, I will get the entire payload inside double quotes as shown above. If I transform that into XML, I end up with a single element containing the escaped XML string.

I've written a little node.js app that also consumes this webservice and it is able to parse the response without any problems, so what's the deal with Mule? Calling out to a webservice and getting a response I can parse should be the most basic thing and I can't make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't know why this was happening, but I updated to Mule ESB 4.1 and I'm not having the problem anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior hints to me that the mime-type of the payload is not being set. Mule transformers use this to parse whatever incoming format.

There is a [bug in mule 3.8.4](https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-12622) (fixed in 3.8.5 & up)  where it is not being set from the content-type response header. A simple work around is to explictly set the mime-type in a set payload message processor immedatly after the http request:

```
<set-payload value="#[payload]" doc:name="Set Payload" mimeType="application/xml"/>
```

This should hopefully lead to more expected behavior.

---

Edit: After reading your response I now suspect that upstream service is actually returning the xml as a json string. So i would try transforming this from json to a java string of xml.

```
 <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.lang.String" doc:name="JSON to Object" mimeType="application/xml"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, this is driving me nuts. Your suggestion didn't work, but I did notice that no matter what I do, how I transform the payload or set the mime type, the payload returned by mule always has content type text/json. That would maybe explain the escaping of quotes and new lines, since json would require it. I can see in the debugger that the response from the webservice has content type of text/xml so I don't see how mule would be getting confused. It makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

In mule HTTP request returns a stream response. So you need to convert it using byte array to string. Then you can use that string to convert xml or json as you need.

Comment: Yep, tried that. Byte array to string results in the string shown in my original post.